# The PeekMessage function in C++ and named pipes

Tags: c++, winapi, message, named-pipes

Regarding:

```
PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)
```

> If hWnd is NULL, PeekMessage retrieves
>   messages for any window that belongs
>   to the current thread, and any
>   messages on the current thread's
>   message queue whose hwnd value is NULL
>   (see the MSG structure). Therefore if
>   hWnd is NULL, both **window messages** and
>   **thread messages** are processed.

Are messages received via a named pipe included in **window messages** and **thread messages**?

Comment: i don't think so.  you would need to do ReadFile or the equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. Named pipes do not send window messages.

The thread messages in this context are special and have nothing to do with named pipes.

Use [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

CODE SAMPLE:

```
void MessageLoop(HANDLE hNamedPipe)
{
    do {
        DWORD res = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &hNamedPipe, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS, MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);
        if (res == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
           /* Handle named pipe -- at this point ReadFile will not block */
        } else if (res == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) {
           MSG msg;
           if (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
              break; /* WM_QUIT */
           TranslateMessage(&msg);
           DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo how to read a data structure from pipe by `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`?

Comment: thanks !But a few wonders,What's `WAIT_OBJECT_0` in your code sample? How should I retrieve a specific **structure** in pipe?

Comment: Pipes don't convey structures. They convey bytes. And WAIT_OBJECT_0 just means the first object in the array of wait handles is in an alerted state - in this case, the array of wait handles only has one object, hNamedPipe.

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows messages and named pipes are completely unrelated. You would need to use the [MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684245(VS.85).aspx) function to wait for either an incoming message or a message on the named pipe.

Note that `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` doesn't actually retrieve the message; check its return value to see if there's a Windows message or data on the named pipe, then use `GetMessage` or `ReadFile` as appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo how to read a data structure from pipe by `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, and how to write to the pipe? I used `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` but it can only deal with strings.